# How can i write company name characters with wave form like shown below

Tags: design-principles, information-graphics

[image]

I want to write my company name in different syyle.

Is it possible that i can write company name "Amoeba" with these type of waveforms.

or at least i can design letter "A" only using these wave forms.

I am not able to get a idea how should i do it. you guys are professional may be give me some ideas

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. Please ask questions about specific issues you are having, even when asking for a review of a specific design, but not general idea-gathering or brainstorming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kinda difficult if you're limited to going up down and right only...but here's some starting points

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: wow , thank u very very much buddy , i got the idea. Is it possible also to design big letter A only with small waves  going up and down

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was thinking when reading the question.